# mysqlrepair --all-databases AND specific table? Or, What is the best way to be checking/repairing MySQL tables frequently?

Tags: mysql

A server has multiple mysql databases with identical schemas. There is a single table within each database that tends to crash and require repairing. We would like to run something like below on a cron.

`mysqlrepair --auto-repair --all-databases --force --silent`

1. For a single table (not large in size) in ~100 databases,
2. Reading http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysqlcheck.html, it states that the tables being processed are locked from other processes. So, am I correct that this should only be something that runs late at night?
3. The command above is missing the option to specify a single table. How can I add this and not have it override the `--all-databases` flag? The `--tables` flag states it

   ```
   Overrides the `--databases` or `-B` option.
   ```

And a related question, short of modifying our application code, is there a better way to be checking/repairing our mysql tables?

Comment: Why do you need to do this *frequently*?

Comment: It would better to solve the problem of *why* you need to do this. Unless you've already figured it out...using this approach should probably be your last option....